# Регулярное выражение для получения свободного коэффициента

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, android-studio

Я написал регулярное выражение для поиска коэффициентов при x1,x2,x3. 
Например: -0.12x1+0.26x2-0.17x3+4.

Вот оно:

`-?[\d]+[\.,\,]?[\d]*(?=x[1-3])`

Но также нужно искать свободный член, типа 4 при этом он может быть дробным и(или) с минусом.

Но из-за плохого понимания регулярок,не могу дополнить. Прошу помочь с этим вопросом.

Comment: Убрал (?=x[1-3]), но теперь нужно выбрать только числа не после x

Comment: думаю проще сначала убрать все переменные `s = s.replaceAll("x\\d*", "");`, а потом уже использовать `-?\d+(?:[\.\,]\d*)?` для выделения чисел

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно ваше выражения разделить на части. В каждую часть будет входить: -(опционально), целая часть, дробная часть (опц.), коэффициент (опц.) либо -(опционально) и коэффициент.
Всё это можно представить следующим regexp
`-?(\d+?(\.\d+)?(x\d*)?|(x\d*))`.
Чтоб найти все части в вашем выражении создайте `Pattern` и пройдитесь циклом:

```
Pattern compile = Pattern.compile("-?(\\d+?(\\.\\d+)?(x\\d*)?|(x\\d*))");
Matcher matcher = compile.matcher("-0.12x1+0.26x2-0.17x3+4");
while(matcher.find())
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
```

P.S. Добавил `|(x\d*)` на случай, если будет только переменная `x` без коэффициента, если для вашего случая это не нужно - можно убрать.